# What's the max stat I can have?

Tags: fallout-shelter

A Room can be affected by the overall stat level of all the Dwellers that are currently assigned to a room. For example, the Water Treatment rooms are affected by Perception.

Now the max stat that a Dweller can have naturally is 10. However, you can give a Dweller an outfit that might boost a certain Stat.

For example, the Armoured Vault Suit grants a +3 to Perception. If a Dweller has 10 Perception already, will this contribute toward the overall "Room Level"? Or would it be better suited giving this to a Dweller who's Perception is below 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cap on effective stat.  Having stat higher than 10 will cause the room to generate resources quicker.

The most notable stat to have higher than 10 is Endurance.  11+ Endurance will make your character immune to radiation damage.